# Term for person conjugation error

Tags: conjugation

What is the right term for the grammatical mistake in the following:

> As someone who loves animals, lions are beautiful.

The error is that the sentence after the comma should have as the object the person in the first sentence, "I". A correct version would be:

> As someone who loves animals, I think lions are beautiful.

What is the right term for the above common mistake?

Comment: Looks like a dangling modifier.

Comment: A reasonable question with an answer that points to the right area of usage.